# Database to Unordered List

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I have a database table, and I want to convert it to a `UL (Unordered List)` with PHP.

I have most of the code down:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('', '', '');
mysql_select_db('');

???

echo '<ul>';
foreach($results['username'] as $user) {
echo "<li>$user</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Where the `???` is, I know I have to perform some sort of DataBase query, but can somebody tell me the specifics?

Comment: Converting a _database_ to an unordered list makes no sense at all.

Comment: Maybe you need this: SELECT column_name,column_name, ... 
FROM table_name;

Comment: @GrantThomas Updated Post: I meant a database _table_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sometable');

echo '<ul>';

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<li>'.implode('; ', $data).'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

`mysql_*`-functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*`-functions instead or just the `mysqli`-class as I did.

Comment: Thanks, this is all I wanted! I am really hurt and saddened that everyone else wanted to dislike my question, but thanks for giving me a solution anyways.